# Specifying dictionary argument with dict() or braces matters in set_bbox

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib home page, there is a link to a tutorial by Nicolas Rougier. In the section of the tutorial entitled "Devil is in the details", the script:

http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/scripts/exercice_10.py

produces the figure displayed on the web page. Line 48 of the script is:

```
label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.65 ))
```

If we replace this line by:

```
label.set_bbox({"facecolor": "white", "edgecolor": "None","alpha":0.65})
```

then the edgecolor request is not taken into account. I would have thought that the two statements above were equivalent. I have asked the author of the tutorial, Nicolas Rougier, about this and he is surprised too. Is this a bug of Matplotlib ?

Comment: This is really strange ... I actually can reproduce this ...

Comment: The devil is indeed in the details...

Comment: I strongly suspect this is related to the `alpha`. The handling of rgb vs rgba colors is finicky.  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: Matplotlib version 1.1.1

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1030

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/842

Answer (score 4):

You can easily determine if the two `dicts` are equivalent:

```
dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.65 ) == \
    {"facecolor": "white", "edgecolor": "None", "alpha":0.65}
```

This is `True`.

*However,* if you type these literals into a Python interpreter, the resulting dictionary `repr`s have the values in different orders.

```
{'alpha': 0.65000000000000002, 'facecolor': 'white', 'edgecolor': 'None'}
{'edgecolor': 'None', 'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.65000000000000002}
```

This may vary based on the version of Python you use, and I believe that in newer versions of Python it varies from run to run of the interpreter; the hash seeding is randomized to prevent dictionaries from being constructed with maliciously poor performance. The above output is from Python 2.6.6 (Win32).

Python `dict`s are unordered, by which we mean that you can't rely on the order. However, when iterating over a dictionary, elements have to come out in *some* order. This order is influenced by the order in which the items are inserted, and though it isn't obvious, they are inserted in two different orders in these two dictionaries: the `dict()` constructor gets a dictionary of keywords, which it then inserts into the constructed `dict`, so in effect the elements of the first `dict` are inserted twice! First in the order you specify them, then in whatever order they ended up in the dictionary constructed in that step.

Hypothesis: There is something in `matplotlib` (or the version of Python you're using) that cares what order dictionary items come out in. In fact, since the second one has its `edgecolor` key first, perhaps it's skipping the first value, or maybe one of the later values has a side effect that causes it to override `edgecolor` (e.g. maybe `facecolor` also sets `edgecolor` to make sure there aren't gaps between faces). This might reasonably be called a bug since the behavior can differ based on the order in which the keywords happen to come out of the dictionary.

Comment: This is the conclusion that I just came to as well.  My My, matplotlib relying on the dict order.  That's unexpected.  I get the same order as you for both the dict constructor and the literal using python2.7.3 on OS-X.  I'm not sure when they turn hash randomization on by default ...

Comment: Doing a little more research, it looks like hash randomization was enabled by default in Python 3.3.

Comment: Looks like `artist.update` iterates over your dictionary and calls functions in the order the items are retrieved, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L667. The problem must then lie in the combination of `set_edgecolor`, `set_facecolor`, and `set_alpha`.

Comment: I bet `facecolor` also sets `edgecolor`, so if it comes later in the dict than `edgecolor`, it overrides the `edgecolor` set earlier.

Comment: @kindall My guess would be if `alpha` come after `edgecolor` it sets a default color instead of skipping touching it.

Comment: @kindall It is stored internally as a `dict` no matter what

Comment: I'm sure, but if you pass them in that way, clearly, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Thank you all. Since everybody confirms it is a bug, I have created an issue on Github tracker: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1934

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the line with:

```
label.set_bbox({"facecolor": "white", "alpha":0.65, "edgecolor": "None",})
```

it works correctly.

I think this is a bug in `set_alpha` or possibly down in the renderer.

As a work-around you can set the line width to 0:

```
label.set_bbox({"facecolor": "white", "edgecolor": "None","alpha":0.65, 'lw':0})
```

which will make sure that the line won't be drawn, independent of what the color/alpha is.

The way the code works, you pass `set_bbox` a `dict` which is then stored in `_bbox`.  At draw time, if `_bbox` is not `None` (and there is no `_bbox_patch`) `_bbox` is passed to `patches.bbox_artist` which is a function (labeled as a debugging function in the docstring!) which uses the `dict` to generate a `Rectangle` object on the fly (which is not returned!).  Someplace in the `set_*` and `draw` in the rectangle is where the bug is.